# Using `case_when()` instead of `if_else`

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use `case_when()` instead of `if(){else}` when I ran into some problems:

```
# if_else version:
(x<- c("apple", "orange", "grapes", "kiwi"))
longstr <- function(x, delim = ",") {
  n <- length(x)
  if (n == 0) {
    ""
  } else if (n == 1) {
    x
  } else if (n == 2) {
    str_c(x[[1]], "&", x[[2]], sep = " ")
  } else {
    front <- str_c(x[seq_len(n - 1)], delim)
    back <- str_c("&", x[[n]], sep = " ")
    str_c(c(front, back), collapse = " ")
  }
}

longstr(x) # gives "apple, orange, grapes, & kiwi"
longstr(c("pea", "pod") # gives "pea & pod"
longstr("egg") # gives "egg"
```

but somehow when I rewrite this using `case_when`, things start to be weird:

```
# case_when version:
longstr2 <- function(x, delim = ",") {
  n <- length(x)
  case_when(
    n == 0 ~ "",
    n == 1 ~ x,
    n == 2 ~ str_c(x[1], "&", x[2], sep = " "),   # weird 1: I can't use x[[1]], but must use only x[1] here
    TRUE ~ {
      not_last <- str_c(x[seq_len(n - 1)], delim)
      last <- str_c("&", x[[n]], sep = " ")       # but somehow here I can still use x[[n]]
      (str_c(c(not_last, last), collapse = " "))}
  )
}

# the weirdest thing:
longstr2(x) 
    # gives "apple, orange, grapes, & kiwi" "apple, orange, grapes, & kiwi" "apple, orange, grapes, & kiwi" "apple, orange, grapes, & kiwi"
    # I don't know why it repeats 4 times
longstr2(c("pea", "pod") 
    # gives "pea & pod" "pea & pod"
    # here it repeats 2 times
longstr2("egg") # gives "egg"
```

I know somehow the weird repeat is linked to my `n`, but I don't know exactly where it went wrong. Any pointer appreciated! thank you!

Comment: This seems like a perfect use for `if(){}else{}` and a weird time to use `case_when` -- which is built for vectors. Why not stick with `if(){}else{}`?

Comment: Note that your first example does not use `if_else` (a dplyr function). It uses `if` and `else`.

Comment: @GregorThomas, yes, I'm just trying to 'practice' using `case_when`; hence was challenging myself to do the same thing with different functions.

Comment: Generally, think of `case_when` as a replacement for `ifelse()`, not for `if(){}else{}`.

Comment: @neilfws, ah, yes, sorry, my bad. edited now

Answer (score 2):

The only change that you need to make is when `n = 1` return `x[1]` so that the length of output is always the same. Unlike, `if`/`else` `case_when` executes it's RHS irrespective of the condition it satisfies hence you see multiple values of the same output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

longstr2 <- function(x, delim = ",") {
  n <- length(x)
  case_when(
    n == 0 ~ "",
    n == 1 ~ x[1],
    n == 2 ~ str_c(x[1], "&", x[2], sep = " "),   
    TRUE ~ {
      not_last <- str_c(x[seq_len(n - 1)], delim)
      last <- str_c("&", x[[n]], sep = " ") 
      (str_c(c(not_last, last), collapse = " "))}
  )
}

longstr2(x) 
#[1] "apple, orange, grapes, & kiwi"

longstr2(c("pea", "pod"))
#[1] "pea & pod"

longstr2("egg") 
#[1] "egg"
```

---

Consider this simple example to understand what I mean by `case_when` executes it's RHS condition irrespective of the condition.

```
n <- 'a'
case_when(is.numeric(n) ~ sqrt(n), TRUE ~ n)
```

This returns

> Error in sqrt(n) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

This is the same error that you get when you do `sqrt('a')` but one would think that `is.numeric(n)` is `FALSE` so it should not even execute `sqrt(n)` but that is not the case.

Comment: Thank you!, but can you explain a bit more on what you mean by *`case_when` executes its RHS irrespective of the condition it satisfies*? isn't assigning the RHS **BASED** on LHS the point of `case_when`?

Comment: also, if anyone could explain why when I use `if/else` I can use `x[[1]]`, but only `x[1]` works with `case_when`?

Comment: @debbybeginner Check my updated answer with a different example which might help you to understand what I mean by that statement.

Comment: thank you for the edit, I see what it's doing. I guess my question is WHY?!  so essentially, even though the condition is not met, the operation associated with that condition still needs to be runnable (i.e no error)? why is it designed this way?